# How to update an image/logo when user(s) reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I have a search input box, and on top of that I have an image/logo.

What is the most efficient way to change image/logo every time user refresh the page ?

```
            <img class="" id="Default Logo" src="/img/logo/logo_3.png" alt="logo" width="150px" > 

            <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter SKU or name to check availability " type="text" />
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search red"></i>
            </span>
```

Right now, I use `logo_3.png`, but I have **10** of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : I use php function : [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

`<img src="/img/logo/<?php echo rand(1,10); ?>.jpg" alt="logo" width="200px" >`

Output - notice image will randomly change !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using backend (and I think you are), then just build the output randomly every time when a user visit your page.

In case of PHP for example:

```
<img id="Logo" src="/img/logo/<?php echo $random_logo_name; ?>.jpg" alt="logo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your img src strings in a JavaScript array and get a random element from the array on page load. Assuming they are all the same width.

```
var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your ID needs to be one word.

```
<img id="default-logo" src="/img/logo/logo_1.png" alt="logo" ... />
```

As long as all of your images are named "logo_*.png", you're fine to randomize the number. Otherwise, you'll need to add the file names into an array, and select the index randomly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $('#default-logo'),
        num = ((Math.random() * 10 | 0) + 1);

    image.prop('src', '/img/logo/logo_' + num + '.png');
});
```

Comment: I got the calculation for `num` from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8063367/1195056).

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in here:

- [How to reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery)
- [Changing img src through jQuery: image won't refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802073/changing-img-src-through-jquery-image-wont-refresh)
- [How to refresh the src of <img /> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997901/how-to-refresh-the-src-of-img-with-jquery)
- [Force refresh an image in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807367/force-refresh-an-image-in-jquery-mobile)

But basically, every time you refresh a page, you should call your backend image server with an appended random number to it (like: img_1, img_2, img_3...)